In a data report about online shopping, can I use "cybershopping" or "e-shopping" as alternatives?
In my experience, whenever I want to replace "online"; "e-", "cyber-" and "virtual" are my go-to options.
In this specific case, I find these alternatives--cybershopping and e-shopping--completely logical. However, there were a lot fewer hits when I searched for them on Ludwig.guru compared to virtual shopping or online shopping.
So, I wonder if there's any problem with either of them.

There's very little "cyber" as far as the shopper's experience is concerned. Looking at pictures online and putting an item in your cart are designed to emulate the non-cyber. "I did some cyber-shopping" seems like something grandma might say to  her grandkids to show them she was cool and keeping up with the times.

Virtual shopping doesn’t work for me. The shopping cart is virtual, but the process of entering into an agreement to provide money in exchange for goods is entirely real. What’s wrong with online?

Thank you both for your advice. Nothing's wrong with "online", but I have to show my range of vocab in my essays and it's good to have alternatives to avoid repetition.

I've just noticed that virtual shopping is a really common phrase. It's everywhere actually, both on websites and dictionaries. Have a look at the third entry in CD.

Stick to "online shopping", "e-shopping” (I've not heard that used often) and "e-commerce". In an essay it's unlikely you'll be using the same term more than three times in a single essay unless there is a 500 word limit. Besides, sapiently using pronouns also shows a good control of the language.

@Mari-LouA I probably won't use "virtual shopping" because it's simply better to listen to native speakers' advice, but not knowing why it's used everywhere yet I can't use it bugs me a little.

In terms of meaning, there isn't much difference between virtual shopping and online shopping. In your native language do you say "online" or its translation? I found this explanation online (not virtually…) https://www.digivate.com/blog/ecommerce-2/online-vs-in-store-shopping/#:~:text=Think%20of%20a%20virtual%20store,bringing%20human%20connection%20to%20eCommerce.

It seems that virtual shopping mimics the experience of retail shopping, you experience the store as if you were there in person; it's more like a 3D tour. In online shopping there is no simulation of a brick and mortar shop, you search for the item, find it, place it in a "cart", confirm, and pay before closing the page.

It seems that you are all talking about sense 2 of this word in the Cambridge Dictionary. However, "virtual shopping" actually lies among the examples of sense 3, where "virtual" means the same as "online". I'd appreciate it if you could check it out via the link I provided above.

virtual shopping can be the online version of window shopping. Think of that. :) And don't forget the poor cousin: web browsing. Using digital media to shop. :) Those should add to your vocabulary.

They are all valid, and all would be understood to mean essentially the same thing. I think "online shopping" is the most commonly used, but I haven't done any research on that, that's just my anecdotal experience.
I would NOT switch back and forth between the terms in a single article. It would create confusion whether you were talking about the same thing or about several different things. Yes, you often hear advice to vary up the vocabularly, especially if you find yourself using the same word multiple times in one sentence. Like "Jack got a job as a car salesman selling cars for a car dealership." You could eliminate some of the repetition by changing that to, say, "Jack got a job as a car salesman selling vehicles for an auto dealership", and everyone would understand that to mean the same thing. But I think if you said, e.g. "Virtual shopping has become increasingly important as e-shopping replaces brick-and-mortar stores and virtual shopping becomes easier to use", I think readers would wonder if you meant that these were 3 different things that were related, or if you were using 3 different terms for the same thing.

Yes, I understand that. That's why I often use another term in the next paragraph. I hope it's a good way to avoid confusing readers because in IELTS tests, you are expected to paraphrase.
